# Did I use too many custom validations in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model use too many **custom validations**.

> I don't know is it a good thing to use custom validations this way?

```
class Lesson
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :end_time, presence: true
  # other validates use rails builtin

  validate :time_range_not_overlap_with_lessons_of_same_class
  validate :time_range_not_overlap_with_lessons_of_same_teacher
  validate :time_range_not_overlap_with_awj_lessons_of_same_teacher
  validate :is_conflict_with_students_cls_lessons
  validate :not_conflict_with_awj_lessons_of_students
end
```

My custom validations (like `time_range_not_overlap_with_lessons_of_same_teacher`) will trigger db queries.
So I wonder is that a correct way to do those validations?
If not should I create a `validate_params` method to replace those custom validations, and called each time before save the record like code below, or are there better ways to do that?

```
def validate_params
   time_range_not_overlap_with_lessons_of_same_class
   # other codes here
end
if lesson.validate_params
  if lesson.save
    #do something
  else
    #other logic here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe custom validation is not a bad idea when you have a requirement to validate something out of those built-in validators provided by Active Model.

A clean way to implement this would be extracting all the custom validators to a separate  validator class inheriting from `ActiveModel::Validator`.

Refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    #your validations
  end 
end

#custom validator added to your model
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 validates_with MyValidator
end
```